# Allow posting on meta without any reputation for the first week

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, privileges

Would it be possible to remove the reputation requirements for posting on meta for the first week, while we iron out all the login problems people are having?

We've already had a few instances of people asking via email, after they found they couldn't ask their question here.

Comment: I will add that the exception for MO is explicitly mentioned in the FAQ on meta.SE: [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587).

Comment: It seems that the exception has outlived its usefulness. Maybe we should ask to revert it.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek That sounds quite reasonable to me. Especially considering that the main site is protected from being abused by posting many similar questions by question bans after enough negatively received posts, but on meta [there is no question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222824/is-there-even-an-automatic-ban-on-meta/222825#222825).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok. I've lowered the reputation requirement here to 1 for the time being.

You'll probably want to revert to 5 at some point just to make your own lives easier, but during the transition dropping it seems like a good idea.

Comment: for the time being