# Privileges on MathOverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

The privileges should probably be set properly and "trusted user" should be put back on the $\geq10000$ accessible privileges.

I find it amusing that I can vote to delete answers, but can't vote to undelete (because the deleted posts won't show).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm; I'm not certain why that was off, but since I was [touching](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/33/allow-posting-on-meta-without-any-reputation-for-the-first-week/34#34) those controls earlier I'll assume I clicked something I shouldn't have. I've reset the privileges that weren't at their defaults - [trusted user is back at 20K](https://mathoverflow.net/privileges/trusted-user).

Comment: Good. Although I should have voted to delete on a couple posts first I suppose... ;-)