# Is there an association bonus for this site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, openid

I used to have a 1 rep MO account. After the SE2.0 merger, I logged in, and while the accounts are showing up associated, I have not received the association bonus.

My MO profile is still the same, though (My homepage and all are different from what I have on the rest of the network).

Looks like the openid-based account merge didn't retroactively apply the association bonus to preexisting accounts.

Comment: (I suspect that higher rep users on MO who have SE accounts have not gotten the bonus either)

Comment: we'll need to backfill these...we'll do so later this morning and several more times as we get people's accounts all hooked up.

Comment: @NickCraver ah, I see. No problem :) (Btw, how was I able to post on meta without 5 rep?)

Comment: Woot, mine just got applied.

Comment: The reputation threshold for Meta has (probably temporarily) [been reduced to 1](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/34/22055).

Comment: I've clicked to create a Google account-based MO account here now, just like I did on Physics SE and a few other SE, and it began with 101 reputation here.

Comment: @LubošMotl Hey there :) Yes, that will work, because you _created_ an MO account. I already had one. The MO and SE accounts were merged, bus since no creating was done no association bonus was awarded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, there sure is...however it's granted when you create the accounts as we go, which isn't really import friendly.  Luckily we already have a way to fix these up, I've just run it to grant it to everyone currently mapped up and we'll run it several more times in the coming days as we get users all mapped up to their existing Stack Exchange accounts.

If you are missing a bonus feel free to comment here and I'll run it again...and of course I'll investigate if it's still missing after that.

Comment: Yep, I have it now :) Thanks!